# Spark execution planning

Tags: apache-spark

I'm trying to better understand the Spark Execution Planning, I find the articles on the internet quite imprecise.

I think we're all familiar with this diagram:

[image]

I was wondering which components are involved in each of those phases :

- Parsing : What component is responsible of parsing the
  Dataframe/Dataset transformations into Trees ? Is it Spark's
  CatalystParser?
- Analyzing to resolve the logical Plan: I think the component involved
  here is the Analyzer and it uses Catalyst rules along with Catalog to
  resolve the logical plan. But i want to know how is the Catalog used
  here ? Is it possible to interfere with the Catalog and the Analyzer
  (I mean Inject some code to do further verification in order to
  resolve the Logical Plan) ? It possible to use a specific Catalog,
  like parsed from Json or so ?
- Optimization: I guess that here we only uses Catalyst along with Rule
  Executors and Sets of predefined rules (like Projection pruning,
  etc.) to optimize the logical plan. I'm i wrong ? Is it possible to
  exclude some rules from the Logical Planning Optimizations or Write
  new sets of rules ?
- Physical Planning & Cost Model: the information I found on some Databricks blogs says that here, we use Catalyst rules and Strategies
  to convert the Logical Plan into one or more physical plan. How is
  that actually done ? Why does the logical plan translated into
  **multiple** physical plan ? For Example, if the logical plan's tree has a Join node, will that node be translated into a physical plan
  with a Sort-Merge Join, another one with a Broadcast Join and so on,
  and then the Cost Model will chose the most economic way to actually
  do that join ?
- Code Generation: I've read somewhere that Tungsten is used here to
  compile parts of queries to java bytecode, but I can't really find
  how this is done, can you explain me this part too ?

I would really appreciate your answers as this topic is kinda getting on my nerves haha, every article I found on the Internet isn't precise enough...

Comment: They are indeed not so easy to follow.

Comment: @thebluephantom yeah..the worst part is that there's contradiction between some blog post i've read and the actual code of these components